# Error in JSON parsing of my JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON code when I try to parse it with JSON.parse('{..}'); in JavaScript
Shows the error "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

```js
var obj= JSON.parse('{
 "single": [
 {"id": "1","question": "this is a question1?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},
 {"id": "2","question": "this is a question2?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},
 {"id": "3","question": "this is a question3?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},
 {"id": "4","question": "this is a question4?","option": ["optionu1","optionu2","optionu3","optionu4"]}
 ],
 "multiple": [
 {"id": "1","question": "this is a multiple question1?","option": ["optionm1","option2lj","option3","option4"]},
 {"id": "2","question": "this is a multiple question2?","option": ["optionm1","option2j","option3","option4"]},
 {"id": "3","question": "this is a multiple question3?","option": ["optionm1","option2gg","option3","option4"]},
 {"id": "4","question": "this is a multiple question4?","option": ["optionm1","option2h","option3","option4"]}
 ],
 "integer": [
 {"id": "1","question": "this is a int question1?"},
 {"id": "2","question": "this is a int question2?"},
 {"id": "3","question": "this is a int question3?"},
 {"id": "4","question": "this is a int question4?"}
 ]}');
```

I think the error is in bracket matching.Please help me rectify it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you replace the `'` characters with backticks `?

Comment: Other then the newlines in the middle of the string, it seems fine to me

Comment: I guess the proof is in the pudding -> https://jsfiddle.net/9nrx7nsk/

Comment: Thank you @adeneo you saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

Use grave accent instead of `'`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(`{
 "single": [
    {"id": "1","question": "this is a question1?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},
    {"id": "2","question": "this is a question2?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},
    {"id": "3","question": "this is a question3?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},
    {"id": "4","question": "this is a question4?","option": ["optionu1","optionu2","optionu3","optionu4"]}
  ],
  "multiple": [
    {"id": "1","question": "this is a multiple question1?","option": ["optionm1","option2lj","option3","option4"]},
    {"id": "2","question": "this is a multiple question2?","option": ["optionm1","option2j","option3","option4"]},
    {"id": "3","question": "this is a multiple question3?","option": ["optionm1","option2gg","option3","option4"]},
    {"id": "4","question": "this is a multiple question4?","option": ["optionm1","option2h","option3","option4"]}
  ],
  "integer": [
    {"id": "1","question": "this is a int question1?"},
    {"id": "2","question": "this is a int question2?"},
    {"id": "3","question": "this is a int question3?"},
    {"id": "4","question": "this is a int question4?"}
  ]
}`);
console.log(obj);
```

It's called [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/template_strings), with it you can i.a. write multi-line strings.

You can also escape new line in normal string using `\` :

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{\
 "single": [\
    {"id": "1","question": "this is a question1?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},\
    {"id": "2","question": "this is a question2?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},\
    {"id": "3","question": "this is a question3?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},\
    {"id": "4","question": "this is a question4?","option": ["optionu1","optionu2","optionu3","optionu4"]}\
  ],\
  "multiple": [\
    {"id": "1","question": "this is a multiple question1?","option": ["optionm1","option2lj","option3","option4"]},\
    {"id": "2","question": "this is a multiple question2?","option": ["optionm1","option2j","option3","option4"]},\
    {"id": "3","question": "this is a multiple question3?","option": ["optionm1","option2gg","option3","option4"]},\
    {"id": "4","question": "this is a multiple question4?","option": ["optionm1","option2h","option3","option4"]}\
  ],\
  "integer": [\
    {"id": "1","question": "this is a int question1?"},\
    {"id": "2","question": "this is a int question2?"},\
    {"id": "3","question": "this is a int question3?"},\
    {"id": "4","question": "this is a int question4?"}\
  ]\
}');
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\` to escape end of a line:

```
var line = '\
  many\
  lines\
';
```

Use template strings if you write in ES6:

```
var line = `
  many
  lines
`;
```